# Why is the lifting map from $S^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ homotopic to the constant map?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have the following proof for the following statement.  But I have a question about some of the reasoning within the proof.

Statement: Prove no map of degree 3 exists from $S^2$ to $T^2$, the torus.

Proof. 
Suppose there exists map degree 3, $f:S^2\longrightarrow T^2$.

$R^2$ is a covering space of $T^2$.  So, $g:R^2\longrightarrow T^2$ is a covering map.

Since $S^2$ is simply connected, then given $f$ there exists a unique continuous function $\widetilde{f}:S^2\longrightarrow R^2$ that lifts the map $f$.

The map $\widetilde{f}$ is homotopic to the constant map.

Projecting back down to $T^2$, we get that $f$ is homotopic to the constant map.  Hence, $f$ has degree zero; a contradiction.

Therefore, there is no map $f$ degree 3. End Proof.

So, my question is: How do we know that $\widetilde{f}$ is homotopic to the constant map?  I feel like it's obvious and I'm not seeing it.  Does it have anything to do with $S^2$ being simply connected? Simply connected means its path connected and its fundamental group is trivial.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2$ is contractible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prove that

> every map $X\to Y$ with $Y$ contractible is homotopic to a constant map.

This is a hint in that I have removed all extraneous information and, therefore, there is almost exatly one thing you can do.

Comment: So, since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is contractible, then the lift is homotopic to a constant map.  So $f=g\circ \widetilde{f}$ is also homotopic to a constant map.

Answer (score 0):

Write $H:[0,1]\times R^2\rightarrow R^2, H(t,x)=t\bar f(x)$ is the requested homotopy between $\bar f$ and the constant map $g(x)=0$.